# Using a Python script in C#

Tags: c#, python, python-2.7, call

I wrote a Python script and written with def's and would now like to call them in C#. Does this happen at all and if so, how?

It also have to work with inputs like "string output = call-funktion(input) #<--- this Funktion have to be linked to Python#"

Comment: Ironpython or Python on .NET do You know?

Comment: dll interop only works for compiled assemblies like c++ that have an external interface. Precompiled languages could be called though their interpreter, check lukemtesta answer